# Call the same view again so that another option can be selected in UITableViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview

**Background:**
Simple app that lets you select a currency from a `UITableViewController`, calls the same view again to make a second choice then takes user to a new view which displays the two selected currencies and exchange rate

So theoretically to me, this is only 2 views. The first being the currency list and the second is presenting chosen currencies/exchange rates. The first view is complete design wise. But I am struggling on how to make the connection between the first and second choice as it's calling the same view. How would I do this?

In my `didSelectRowAt`, I would typically performSegue but how do I call the same view and record the value selected from the first view? An idea I had was call a function that would record if an option is selected, and if so, call the new view else call the same view again but I'm not sure how I would implement this. Any help is appreciated!

My code thus far:

```
import UIKit

class SelectCurrencyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // Get the JSON data to insert into the table
    func parseJSONData()-> Array<Any> {
        var finalArray = [Any]()
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "currencies", withExtension: "json") {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
                if var jsonArray = jsonResult as? [String] {

                    while jsonArray.count > 0 {
                        let result: [String] = Array(jsonArray.prefix(2))
                        finalArray.append(result)
                        jsonArray.removeFirst(2)
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        return finalArray
    }

    func checkOptionsCount()-> Int{
        // somehow check if option selected?
        return 1 
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return parseJSONData().count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCellController
        if let array = parseJSONData()[indexPath.row] as? [String]{
            cell.countryCodeLabel.text = array[0]
            cell.currencyLabel.text = array[1]
            cell.countryFlag.image = UIImage(named: array[0])
        }
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        // if this is 1st time, present view again
        if (checkOptionsCount() == 1){



        // if this is 2nd time, show new view
        } else if (checkOptionsCount() == 2){
             // performSegue with new view 


        } else {
            print("How did I get here")
        }
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing your code, I am assuming you are using storyboards. One way to accomplish what you want can be like this:

1. In Interface Builder select your SelectCurrencyTableViewController and add Storyboard ID to it: [image]
2. Add a property where you will store your selected currency to SelectCurrencyTableViewController, something along these lines:

   ```
   class SelectCurrencyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

       var selectedCurrency: Currency?
       //...
   }
   ```
3. Then in didSelectRow:

   ```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


       // if this is 2nd time, show new view
       if let selected = selectedCurrency {

           // performSegue with new view 

       // if this is 1st time, present view again
       // these is no selected currency passed from previous view controller, so this is the first time
       } else {

           //get view controller from storyboard using storyboard id (replace "Main" with your storyboard's name
           let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
               .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SelectCurrencyTableViewController") as! SelectCurrencyTableViewController
           vc.selectedCurrency = //place code for getting first currency based on indexPath.row here
           show(vc, sender: self)
       }
   }
   ```